# How can I modify the size of SpriteKit nodes in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, skspritenode

In my app, for one screen, I am setting the size and centering the background of a SpriteKit node. For example, I'm setting the size of the background subview as follows:

```
backgroundNode.size = self.frame.size
```

While this is working on the *iPhone 6 Plus*, the smaller screen/lower resolution of the *iPhone 5* means the default size of the other nodes makes is too large to fit within their scene.

How can I force other nodes conform to the size of the background node?
I wanted to divide each subview's size by the background subview's size, but math operations can't be done directly on the size property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***SpriteKi*t** scenes (`SKScene`) contain nodes, nodes (`SKNode`), which have `size` and `position` properties (of type [`CGSize`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgsize) and [`CGPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgpoint), respectively).

***UIKit*** [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview).[`frame`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622488-init) and [`bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622580-bounds) properties are a [`CGRect`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect) structs comprised of the same [`CGSize`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgsize) and [`CGPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgpoint) type structs.

So it really helps to understand how to work with `CGRect`, `CGSize` and `CGPoint`.

Be aware, `CGRect`, `CGSize` and `CGPoint` as structs, in Swift, are always passed by value to functions, not by references as classes are, so you can't modify fields inside the structs passed into a function, and have them propagate back to the caller's copy of the struct without taking extra steps.

Because size and position properties are compound types, you can't use them like scalars in simple in math and logic operations; as they contain multiple properties.

For example:

- `CGSize` contains `width` and `height` properties,
- `CGPoint` consists of `x` and `y` properties.

If  want to divide size, you have to access width and height properties of the `CGSize` struct individually.

You can assign the size in one operation (i.e. single constructor):

```
node.size = CGSize(
   width:  node.size.width  / backgroundNode.size.width,
   height: node.size.height / backgroundNode.size.height)
```

Or you could do it discretely:

```
node.size.width  = node.size.width  / backgroundNode.size.width
node.size.height = node.size.height / backgroundNode.size.height
```

When dealing with `CGRect` fields, sometimes it's useful to deal with it as a single entity. For example,

```
 view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
```

Others sometimes it's more practical to set `size` and `origin` properties separately:

```
 view.frame.origin = CGPoint (x: 0, y: 0)
 view.frame.size   = CGSize  (width: 10, height: 10)
```

or even:

```
 view.frame.origin.x     = 0
 view.frame.origin.y     = 0
 view.frame.size.width   = 10
 view.frame.size.height  = 10
```

It's also worth knowing about the "zero" static property of each of the struct, as convenient crisp shorthand equivalents:

```
 CGRect .zero   ...    CGRect  (x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
 CGPoint.zero   ...    CGPoint (x: 0, y: 0)
 CGSize .zero   ...    CGSize  (width: 0, height: 0)
```

> *<sub>If you do a lot of adjusting of size and position, to reduce code bloat, you might consider borrowing or developing convenient Swift extensions to `CGRect, CGSize and CGPoint` to simplify applying delta values to sizes or origins.</sub>*

Comment: you sir is a frieking legend!! ill try that out right now!

Comment: How effective is this tho? I feel like basing the size and position with the background or the node behind it seems so perfect, but i wanna be aware of its limitations

Comment: A bit out of the scope of the question. I was merely illustrating *how* to do it, not advising whether it should be done or will size your sprites properly.  I don't think division is right as shown, because the bigger the background the *smaller* the node. You need to decide what effect you want, what to prioritize.  I wonder if  you *really* want to make sprites scale with screen size. Might be better to keep their size constant relative to the eye and give them more room to move on larger iPhones

Comment: There's a lot of [scaling](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) that goes into iPhone rendering in `iOS` behind the scenes (no pun intended). Perhaps you can pick a sprite size and check it out on various iPhone simulators in XCode to see what it really looks like to help decide what you want.  This article may help you get the desired effect: https://www.raywenderlich.com/49695/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1

Comment: After staying up all night I got it!!!
I set the size of the node equal to the frame size and change the node's yScale and xScale. And BOOM!! They look the same to every single screens

`redFlagNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redFlag")`
        `redFlagNode.position = CGPoint(x: frameWidth / 6, y: frameHeight / 2.2)`
        `redFlagNode.size = CGSize(width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight)`
        `redFlagNode.xScale = CGFloat(0.67)`
        `redFlagNode.yScale = CGFloat(0.9)`

Comment: If you use the SceneEditor GUI, the size fields merely change the xScale and yScale. clearlight's programatic solution is correct.